# Simple change to be made in vb

Tags: csv, ms-access, vba

```
Sub Command3_Click()
      Dim fs As FileSystemObject
      Dim f As TextStream
      Dim a As Variant
      Dim i As Long

      Set fs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

      ' Read file into array
       If fs.FileExists("C:\Abhi\Code test\rbc.csv") Then
           Set f = fs.OpenTextFile("C:\rbc.csv", ForReading, False)
           a = Split(f.ReadAll, vbNewLine, -1, vbTextCompare)
           f.Close
       Else
           MsgBox "The file path is invalid.", vbCritical, vbNullString
           Exit Sub
       End If
      ' Write line > 1 to file
      Set f = fs.OpenTextFile("C:\rbc.csv", ForWriting, True)
      For i = 1 To UBound(a)
        f.WriteLine a(i)
      Next
      f.Close
End Sub
```

This is the code I am using . I want to delete the first line of my CSV file and use all the other lines. In my input csv file the first line is always

> 01-JUL-2014,RBC_BASELII_07012014,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,

Now if I remove the commas and just keep one comma, the program works fine . But if I keep the line in the original form with 10-12 commas , the whole file gets empty when I run the program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have a string array after Split() command. Try the following (start iteration from i=2):

```
  For i = 2 To UBound(a)
    f.WriteLine a(i)
  Next
```

Regards,

Comment: Thanks for your reply but I tried it now and it's not working .

Comment: So, what is the output? What do you mean by 'not working'? Please be more specific. Regards,

Comment: Sorry ! The whole text gets deleted , I mean all the lines . The file size goes to zero from like 1 mb.

Comment: After the line a = Split(f.ReadAll, vbNewLine, -1, vbTextCompare) check if the array a contains any text.

Comment: Array has some data after the split line .

Comment: Sorry for bugging in but now I realized that even if I remove a single comma from the end manually , the program works fine . What can be the reason

Comment: You may be able to answer this after I tell you the final thing . If I open the file and even without making any changes I save it , the program works and only one line is deleted but if I don't open the file , it goes empty when the program runs

Comment: Array must contain multiple lines. You just skip the first one and then do processing of the rest (as per your task description).

Comment: The discussion got lengthy, which is not recommended on this site. It now looks like remote debugging, so I am closing this discussion thread. If you have more questions, please accept the answer given to you and post your additional questions separately. Thanks and regards,